# Encryption and Decryption error in my program (C)

Tags: c, encryption

So i've been working on an encryption project in C but i have ran into some problems and they're very awkward.

The encryption is based off XOR encryption. I added base64 encoding to the output as well.

Im fairly new to C so be aware my mistakes could be very dumb. Any tips regarding my coding or even changing the algorithm itself could possibly help.

My problem is I can decrypt a encrypted string as long as the length of the key is the same as the original, and some characters in the key can be changed.

for example if i encrypted "Hello World" with "Key123" i can decrypt it with "Key124"...

Of course this poses a major problem and i dont know how to solve it.

I havent tried anything to fix this because not a lot of answers online explain whats going on.

So heres the encrypt function...

```c
// encryption process
char * encrypt(char strinp[], char key[]){
    int keylen = strlen(key);
    char cipher_1;
    // the stupid char is causing me my problems with stack smashing
    char cipher_2[0x10000];

    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(strinp); i++){
      
        cipher_1 = strinp[i] + keylen;
        cipher_2[i] = cipher_1 ^ key[i];


    }

    const char * data = cipher_2;
    size_t input_size = strlen(cipher_2);
    char * encoded_data = base64_encode(data, input_size, &input_size);
    return encoded_data;

}
```

Heres the decryption process...

```c
char * decrypt(char strinp[], char key[]){
    int keylen = strlen(key);
    char cipher_1;
    char cipher_2;

    // Decoding process
    const char * decode = strinp;
    size_t decode_size = strlen(decode);
    char * decoded_data = base64_decode(decode, decode_size, &decode_size);

    //decrypting process
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(decoded_data); i++){
        cipher_2 = decoded_data[i] ^ key[i];
        cipher_1 = cipher_2 - keylen;

        printf("%c", cipher_1);
    }

}
```

and heres the github link for the whole code

https://github.com/N0tA1dan/Krypton-C/blob/main/src/krypton.c

Comment: In the `encrypt` function, what happens if `strlen(key) != strlen(strinp)` (like in your example)? You have the same problem in the `decrypt` function.

Comment: Also this line is broken: `size_t input_size = strlen(cipher_2);`. This will truncate the result any time equivalent bytes in the key and the plaintext happen to line up (x xor x == 0). Do you really need this ad hoc scheme rather than using an established cipher like AES? Your code is very buggy (both logic and memory management), and I'm not sure where to start helping you. But probably the first issue is that your cipher is fundamentally insecure, even if you fix the bugs. There's no way to make "xor a reusable key directly to the plaintext" secure.